# Volley: unable to set break point for onResponse method

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley Library to make network calls and I am using it for the first time. I am trying to set a break point in `onResponse` method but the break point is getting toggled on `JsonObjectRequest`. Following is my code

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, urlL1, "", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(CVLenderApp.TAG, response.toString());
               // I would like to set the break point at this line
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Success", 3000).show();
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(CVLenderApp.TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("userName", "name");
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        CVLenderApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
```

I hope I'm doing a small mistake, but I'm unable to figure that out.

Thank you,
Anudeep Reddy.

Comment: That means `onErrorResponse` called. For POST request's parameter, override getBody instead of getParams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, for POST request's parameters, override `getBody` instead of `getParams`

Moreover, if your project uses Google's official Volley, then try the following sample code:

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("userName", "name");
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // do something...
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // do something...
                }
            });
            MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: From where can I download Google's official Volley?

Comment: Read [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/volley/index.html). Pay attention to `Git clone ...`